# Change style and/or conditional style of the selection button

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I would like to ask you, it's any way to add custom style to the selection button (cell?) I need set for example red color for one cell, yellow color for another one cell.

It's possible to remove check picture from this selection button and replace it to standard checkbox input?

I mean this (original selection buttons):

[image]

and I would like to change like this (expected selection buttons):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
    .ui-grid-row > [ui-grid-row] .ui-grid-disable-selection {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .ui-grid-row.ui-grid-row-selected > [ui-grid-row] .ui-grid-disable-selection {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

To change the icon you'll need to add an [**icon font**](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/square-o/). The default UI Grid font doesn't have the checkbox. Then you can do something like so:

```
.ui-grid-icon-ok:before {
    content: '\f096';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Note: I used my browser's document inspector to identify these selectors (F12 in Windows). You should become familiar with that tool as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I thought that there are more colors that 2, there depends on some value in data - for example, if data.status == 1 then cell where is selection icon will be red, if data.status == 2 then yellow, if data.status == 3 then green and so..

Comment: In that case, your question wasn't complete and/or clear. Please edit it accordingly or create a new one with a more specific question.