# How I can change selection button color depends on data from json?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I would like to ask you, it's any way to add custom style to the selection button (cell?) I need set for example red color for one cell, yellow color for another one cell.

Colors are depends on data from json, for example if data.status == 1 then color will be red, if data.status==2 then color will be yellow, if data.status==3 then color will be green, and so.

There must be colored whole cell (not only icon).

Please see this link: [Change style and/or conditional style of the selection button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015165/change-style-and-or-conditional-style-of-the-selection-button#) - like second picture

Comment: Have you tried with `ng-class`?

Comment: but I don't known how I can bind ng-class conditional to first (selection) column, it's generated automatically by plugin

Comment: So can you provide any plunker or something?

Comment: Example: `ng-class="{'red': (data.status == 1), 'anotherClassName': (data.status != 1)}"`

Comment: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/TbDbeSBJApdvB9cAPIdR?p=preview) 'http://plnkr.co/edit/TbDbeSBJApdvB9cAPIdR?p=preview'

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to control the response data from the server, it may be better to include a data attribute such as "status-color" with a color value (i.e. "red", "green", etc).

You could do something like this in your AngularJS controller 
    (Assuming you're grabbing the response data from the server in your controller or as a dependency in a route):

```
$scope.status_color = data.status_color;
```

And then in your view:

```
<div class="{{status_color}}></div>
```

You'd need to define the expected color classes in a CSS file somewhere, but it should work just fine. You can also use ngClass, documentation on that here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: thanks you, this answer is very useful for me, but how I implement <div class="{{status_color}}></div> to the first column which is generated automatically by plugin? Please see plnkr.co/edit/TbDbeSBJApdvB9cAPIdR?p=preview